# Where should grow my echeveria?

Tags: succulents, rain, slugs

I have a small Echeveria that I bought a few months ago and I've been growing it outside.  I live in the UK where rain, slugs, and snails are very common. It gets a lot of full sun during the summer outside and its leaves are constantly being eaten by slugs one by one and the rain is slightly overwatering it which is dangerous for a succulent.

I do have a window which faces directly at the sun where all my other plants get a lot of sun and they are also safe from the rain and slugs so should I keep my echeveria at that window or leave it outside?

I've tried putting rocks on soil and using pesticides but none of them keep the slugs away from it.

Comment: Slugs need unique bait sprinkled nearby to stop them. 'Diatomaceous earth' is scratchy to them and worth a try, too. For dryness, choose a no-rain location where you control watering.

Answer (score 1):

Echeveria are pretty cold resistant, but what they can't cope with is lots of rain and cold together, so best brought in at the end of summer (I use the term summer laughingly because we seem to be having a permanent wet autumn recently). I'm not surprised you're having a slug/snail problem because its been so wet and given the weather conditions, I'd suggest you move it somewhere out of the rain and into drier conditions rather than trying to fend off the army of molluscs we have this year. If you move it to the windowsill inside, it's probably best to leave it there till next summer - plants tend to suffer a bit of shock being frequently moved from one environment to another.

Answer (score 0):

When I Google it, I see a number of methods to control slugs.  I don't believe that most of them work (especially sharp surfaces).  Suggestions

- Manual - Just pick them off and dispatch them.
- Slug Pellets - there are various ones around.
- Beer Traps - bury a shallow dish, with rim level to ground and fill it with beer.

We use the pellets and they seem to work.  Friends say that the beer trap works.